# How to make dropdown menu responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Hi I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown menu inside a table. I am trying to implement a simple dropdown menu in w3schools.

```js
    /* When the user clicks on the button,
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        overflow: auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
    
    .show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
    <table>
    <tr><td>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </td></tr>
    <table>
```

two dropdown appears but takes the same position. Can someone help me with responsive positioning of this dropdown menu? Thanks in advance

Comment: well. when you click on one of the buttons, both `dropdown-content` get class`show` . so they both show up. i guess that's the problem. you need to separate the buttons with their corresponding  `dropdown-content`

Comment: Yes I need help with that css part. Cant I use single class to position them below each button? Can you please help me? @MihaiT

Comment: they are positioned correctly. but they both open at the same time. that's why you think they are in the same position. but in fact you are seeing both dropdowns opened at the same time. i will make a JQ solution

Comment: I added tags. I need some help with javascript. @MihaiT

Comment: added a JQ solution. with JavaScript , the code it's much more complicated and long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

made a JQ script and it works as you want

***Explanation***

this script works with any number of `.dropdowns`

so, on click on each button with class `.dropbtn` first we find the corresponding `.dropdown-content` , the one that should open when clicking on the respective button.

for that we use the [**sibling()**](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method which selects the ' brother ' with class `.dropdown-content` of the clicked button. and then. using the [**slideToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) method, we hide and show on click the before-found `.dropdown-content` .

but we also need to close previously opened `.dropdown-content`s when clicking and opening another `.dropdown-content` .

in order to do that, we need to find the already opened `.dropdown-content` ( if there is one )  and close it. so we use the [**parents()**](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method to find the grandparent ( `tr` ) of the current clicked button  . that's why we use `parents()` instead of `parent()` which only selects the immediate parent not all ancestors.

after finding the grandparent, with `siblings()`  we find the other `tr`s, and inside them we **[find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** the `.dropdown-content` that is visible, using **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method together with the **[:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)** selector. To this found div with class `.dropdown-content` that is visible, we apply the **[slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)** method that hides it and so, only the dropdown that corresponds to the last clicked button is being shown

```js
    $(".dropbtn").on("click",function(){
      var showMe = $(this).siblings(".dropdown-content")
      $(showMe).slideToggle()
       var visible_drop = $(this).parents('tr').siblings().find('.dropdown-content').filter(":visible")
       $(visible_drop).slideUp()
})
```

```css
.dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        overflow: auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
    <table>
    <tr><td>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </td></tr>
    <table>
```

Comment: That's working.Thank you.you saved my day... @Mihai T

Comment: glad i could help. i will also write an explanation of the script so others seeking this answer will understand more easily . cheers :D

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that all the dropdown have the same id, and there is a conflict with the js code.

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
```

When you click over the dropdown the js allways open the first element and not the second. So you will need to change the id to make it unique or change the selection of the element you want to show.

Comment: I have edited my code above. I tried changing id but its not working as expected. Can you please help me? @Albert Font

Answer (score 0):

The same JS function is called from the two buttons. When you click on one button, myFunction is called and it displays the two dropdown-content at the same time. To correct this, you have to call a different function from each button, something like this :

```
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.remove("show");
 document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }


function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
    document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
        }
```

I don't really like this solution though... Also, I think you should keep the two buttons in the same table row so the dropdown content doesn't appear oddly for the first button.

Comment: I am not only having two button. I am working with it dynamically I cant have solid count. How to make this code dynamic? Can you please help me? @CitizenFifty Two